# Issue with Python3.11, tensorflow 2.16.1, Cuda12, CuDNN8 - Linux Mint 21.3

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I am unable to activate GPU support on my machine with tensorflow.
My machine config are as follows:
OS: Linux Mint 21.3
GPU: RTX 3060

---

Cuda and CuDNN are properly configured and I am using GPU support in Pytorch

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Nov_22_10:17:15_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.3, V12.3.107
Build cuda_12.3.r12.3/compiler.33567101_0

$ python
Python 3.11.8 (main, Feb 26 2024, 21:39:34) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.backends.cudnn.version()
8902
```

---

For tensorflow, I have installed tensorrt and als0 .whl for python3.11 from CUDA/tensorflow website. Still I am getting the following erorr. This is driving my crazy. Your guidance and help is required

---

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

Error message:
2024-03-12 16:42:26.872831: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-03-12 16:42:27.413655: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-03-12 16:42:27.784773: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-03-12 16:42:27.804995: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```